# How to change main admin email address in WordPress without notification and confirmation processes

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I have created one site in staging server I want to change admin email address for that staging site. 
Because I want to test something on staging site at that time, and I want that no email is being sent to client (original admin email), I want to change main admin email.

But when I change admin email I get confirmation link on to my new admin email address.

The Admin email address won’t change until I click on the link in the confirmation email.

After I click on the confirmation link, the original admin is receiving notice of Admin Email Change.

I want to disable notice of Admin Email Change and also new Admin Email Address confirmation link in WordPress.

How I do that? Could you please help me?  Is there any code for this?

[image]

Comment: change admin email from DataBase and replace with your own email.. if you don't have DB access then i think you are going to some illegal activity

Comment: there are several ways to get access to the DB - but if you don't have access to Phpmyadmin or something similar, and don't know how to access it with other programs, then you can use search and replace plugins, or sql plugins, this way you can still run the query

Comment: install adminer plugin it gets you the database access.

Comment: or if it is a simple S and R, then you can use this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/

Comment: or with SQL : https://wordpress.org/plugins/sql-executioner/

Comment: @developerme can you access FTP or cpanel?

Comment: do you have access wp-admin access?

Comment: install adminer and check my answer

Answer (score 127, accepted):

There is a 'secret' settings page which lets you change all of the settings in the options table.

Access it by changing the URL from /options-general.php to /options.php

Comment: I've been working with WP for like 8 solid years and I never knew about this page. Awesome! You'd be surprised how many admin emails I get cause the new owners just refuse to change the site admin and that stupid email confirmation block prevents me from doing it for them. Never again! You spared me endless harassment in ancient site notifications.

Comment: This is not working anymore, I've tried, saved changes, bot back to options-general and notification of pending mail was there.

Comment: Works for me on 5.1.1. There are two fields to change: 'admin_email' and 'new_admin_email'

Answer (score 17):

There are few ways to change admin email without using a 3rd party plugin.

Also, besides admin_email, there is another value that needs to be changed. 
No matter that you change `admin_email` value in DB, a confirmation notice will remain, 
unless you change `new_admin_email` too.

**Updating via the database:**

In case of updating option via DB directly, there are two options that need to be changed: `admin_email` and `new_admin_email`.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'admin@example.com' WHERE 
option_name LIKE 'admin_email' 
OR 
option_name LIKE 'new_admin_email';
```

**note:** While by default every WordPress database has `wp_` prefix for its tables, they can be changed, so check in *wp-config.php* for `$table_prefix` value.

**Updating via options.php:**

Another way without the use of some plugin is as mentioned accessing secret page `/wp-admin/options.php`. However, there might be too many options, and due to a number of `$_POST` variables limit set for each server differently, having it quite impossible to change it that way.

*See more about `max_input_vars`*
https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php

**Updating via functions.php in active theme:**

You could set one time code (and delete it after) in *functions.php* of your active theme to update these options:

```
update_option( 'admin_email', 'admin@example.com' );
```

and

```
update_option( 'new_admin_email', 'admin@example.com' );
```

Put these within some `admin_init` action callback.

**Updating via wp-cli:**

Another way to update Admin email is via wp-cli ( if you have access to terminal ssh):

```
wp option update admin_email 'admin@example.com'
```

and

```
wp option update new_admin_email 'admin@example.com'
```

*see more about wp option commands:*

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/option/update/

Comment: So there is always a new_admin_email?  and it will be the same as admin_email once confirmed via the UI?

Answer (score 8):

The one that you are trying to replace is actually the email in Wordpress settings, not the wp user email. That one can be changed directly in database in the table `wp_options` where `option_name` is `admin_email`

Or with the given update query:

```
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'new@email.com' WHERE `option_name` = 'admin_email';
```

Comment: This is the best answer as `options.php` does not always save/work correctly

Answer (score 3):

**Note: Get dump and try it on local first. Don't test in production.**

Change with DB

```
//email
UPDATE `wp_users` SET `user_email` = "new_email_address" WHERE `wp_users`.`user_login` = "admin";

//password
UPDATE `wp_users` SET `user_pass` = MD5('new_password_here') WHERE `wp_users`.`user_login` = "admin";
```

[Check This too](http://cloudhost.com.ng/blog/how-to-change-your-word-press-admin-email-from-database/)

Comment: he mention in comments that i have no access of DataBase

Comment: That was not in question and it added parallelly  while I'm adding answer

Comment: @BilalAhmed That was my doubt if have no access how i do that?

Comment: I think this query only changing admin login email id.

Comment: @developerme as you asked **How to change Admin email address** change email only

Comment: I found that admin email in database in wp_option table.On wp_option table there we can see that admin_email option that area we need to change

Answer (score 2):

The network admin email is changed from wp_sitemeta table. Use following query in phpmyadmin or any mysql client in order to update the email if you are unable to change from network admin settings.

```
UPDATE `wp_sitemeta` SET `meta_value` = 'the_new_email@abc.com' WHERE `meta_value` = 'the_old_email@abc.com';
```

Note: please use the table prefix accordingly used in db if it is not wp in your case.

[image: look at the image of wp_sitemeata table if you want to know the entries to be changed.]

Answer (score 1):

Easier to use phpMyAdmin

wp_options > admin_email

Answer (score 1):

You have to enter mysql server

and run the following query

```
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'mail@email.com' WHERE `option_id` = 6;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to some of the other answers that there might not be a 'new_admin_email' row in the options table.

The 'new_admin_email' value only gets set after you attempt to change the original admin email via the normal settings page (/wp-admin/options-general.php). And it will be deleted if you cancel the pending change.

Answer (score 0):

Run this query, This will change the email id without any confirmation

```
UPDATE `wp_users` SET `user_email` = 'newemail' WHERE `user_email` = 'old_email';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I wrote a plugin to rollback the confirmation link feature. You can download it on the .org repo:

[Change Admin Email Setting Without Outbound Email](https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-admin-email-setting-without-outbound-email/)

Here is the code:

```
<?php
/*
 Plugin Name: Change Admin Email Setting Without Outbound Email
 Plugin URI: https://wp-bdd.com/change-admin-email/
 Description: Restores functionality removed since WordPress 4.9. Allows the changing of the admin email by admins in single site without outbound email or recipient email credentials.
 Version: 1.0
 Author: John Dee
 Author URI: https://wp-bdd.com/
*/

$ChangeAdminEmailPlugin = new ChangeAdminEmailPlugin;

class ChangeAdminEmailPlugin{

    public function __construct(){

        //This plugin doesn't do anything unless it's WordPres version +4.9 and single site
        if($this->isWordPressMinimiumVersion("4.9.0") && (!( is_multisite()))){
            //pulls the default actions
            remove_action( 'add_option_new_admin_email', 'update_option_new_admin_email' );
            remove_action( 'update_option_new_admin_email', 'update_option_new_admin_email' );

            //When you actually complete the change, another email gets fired to the old address
            //this filter overides this:
            add_filter('send_site_admin_email_change_email', function(){return FALSE;}, 10, 3 );

            //hooks our own custom method to update the email
            add_action( 'add_option_new_admin_email', array($this, 'updateOptionAdminEmail'), 10, 2 );
            add_action( 'update_option_new_admin_email', array($this, 'updateOptionAdminEmail'), 10, 2 );

            //this fixes the text in English. Translators wanted for other languages.
            add_action('wp_after_admin_bar_render', array($this, 'modifyOptionsGeneralPHPForm'));
        }
    }

    public function updateOptionAdminEmail( $old_value, $value ) {
        update_option( 'admin_email', $value );
    }

    public function isWordPressMinimiumVersion($version){
        global $wp_version;
        if (version_compare($wp_version, $version, ">=")) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    //Changes the form on admin area options-general.php. Doesn't do anything unless on this page.
    public function modifyOptionsGeneralPHPForm(){
        $screen = get_current_screen();
        if($screen->base == "options-general"){
            add_filter( 'gettext', array($this, 'filterText'), 10, 3 );
        }
    }

    //Changes the English text of WP core. Inspired by https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188332/override-default-wordpress-core-translation
    public function filterText( $translated, $original, $domain ) {
        if ( $translated == "This address is used for admin purposes. If you change this we will send you an email at your new address to confirm it. <strong>The new address will not become active until confirmed.</strong>"){
            $translated = __("This address is used for admin purposes.");
        }
        return $translated;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the email confirmation by just adding the following code in your theme function.php

```
    remove_action( 'add_option_new_admin_email', 'update_option_new_admin_email' );
remove_action( 'update_option_new_admin_email', 'update_option_new_admin_email' );

/**
 * Disable the confirmation notices when an administrator
 * changes their email address.
 *
 * @see http://codex.wordpress.com/Function_Reference/update_option_new_admin_email
 */
function wpdocs_update_option_new_admin_email( $old_value, $value ) {

    update_option( 'admin_email', $value );
}
add_action( 'add_option_new_admin_email', 'wpdocs_update_option_new_admin_email', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'update_option_new_admin_email', 'wpdocs_update_option_new_admin_email', 10, 2 );
```